# Angularjs cannot find intellisense

Tags: angularjs

I am using visual studio 2010. When i am going to install angularjs and Angularjs UI Bootstrap from Microsoft nuget. In my index page i already set angularjs.min.js reference but angularjs intellisense not working. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue.

The visual studio IDE will scan any js files referenced in the HTML files and use them if neccesary (for the intellisense etc).

My problem was i was referencing Angularjs using the CDN/http:// addresses and thus Visual studio did not have any information on angular.

Try downloading the angularjs js file directly and include in your project and reference in your index.html, rebuild (just in case) and try again and hopefully it should work.

Hope i helped.